# How to manually power-on the webcam?

Tags: webcam, acpi, udev

I have a Clevo laptop with a built in webcam, on the keyboard there's a helpful <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> hotkey that seems to power the device on and off. I'd like to have some control over the webcam without needing to trigger the hotkey, but I'm not certain on where I need to look to find what it's triggering.

Do I need to look at the Xorg keymaps? Or the udev rules? Or something in ACPI? I've tried digging around in all three and I've yet to find anything massively relevant.

Comment: Why do you need this? There's no point turning on the webcam unless you're currently recording.

Comment: Under some bizarre, non-predictable and random happenstance it'll occasionally power itself off on shutdown and not restart when requested. So not necessarily switching the camera onto record, but making sure the device was powering up.